# How do I access 'cy.load()' etc from outside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, cytoscape.js

I'm very new to both JavaScript and the cytoscape.js library. I have been playing around with the example code but I am stuck with something basic.

Essentially, what I want to be able to do is setup my basic options and style, and then be able to load my nodes and edges from a JSON structure returned by my server. I know I can use cy.load from within the 'ready' function as I am below:

```
$(loadCy = function(){

options = {
showOverlay: false,
minZoom: 0.5,
maxZoom: 2,

style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
  .selector('node')
    .css({
      'content': 'data(name)',
      'font-family': 'helvetica',
      'font-size': 14,
      'text-outline-width': 3,
      'text-outline-color': '#888',
      'text-valign': 'center',
      'color': '#fff',
      'width': 'mapData(weight, 30, 80, 20, 50)',
      'height': 'mapData(height, 0, 200, 10, 45)',
      'border-color': '#fff'
    })
  .selector(':selected')
    .css({
      'background-color': '#000',
      'line-color': '#000',
      'target-arrow-color': '#000',
      'text-outline-color': '#000'
    })
  .selector('edge')
    .css({
      'width': 2,
      'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
    })
,

ready: function(){
  cy = this;
  cy.load({
     nodes: [
      { data: { id: "n1" } },
      { data: { id: "n2" } }
      ],
     edges: [
      { data: { id: "e1", source: "n1", target: "n2" } }
      ]
    }) 
 }
 };

  $('#cy').cytoscape(options);

     });
```

but I'd like to know if there is a way to have everything else setup on document ready and then later on, say on a button click access cy.load?

For example:

```
<script>
  $("#button").click( function()
  {
     cy.load(<data returned from server>)
  }
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code. Essentially Cytoscape draws the graphs within this DIV:

```
 <body>
   <div id="cy"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Looks to me like it should work (as with every other jQuery function).

Comment: Hi Max, Yes I have tried it.  I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'load'.

Comment: That's just wrong... apparently `cy` is being resolved to a `div`... Is there any other code you use for initialization? Does `cytoscape` come with its own initializer?

Comment: ok sorry, I've updated the question with the div that would exist. This is all taken from the example at http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/ . I am very new to JS as I mentioned in my OP, but yes I believe it has an 'initialiser' as you stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your example `var cy` is not defined and thus js fetches the div with `id="cy"`

you need to add this (as in the [documentation](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/initialisation))

```
$("#cy").cytoscape(options);
var cy = $("#cy").cytoscape("get");
```

Comment: Thank you!! I seriously missed it... not sure how.